# Run for loop over subsets in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Can you run a for loop over the names of multiple subsets? 
For instance, I now have subsets dfVC1 up until dfVC20 and I would like to do something like:

```
for x in range(20):
      print(dfVC[x])
```

I get this doesn't work... but wonder if there is a way to do this.

Comment: `for x in dfVC: print(x)`.

Comment: What type of object is `dfVC`?

Comment: Are `dfVC1`, `dfVC2`, ..., `dfCV20` all individual variables?

Comment: Basically subsets of the dataset (sliced by year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your 'subsets' in this case are variables, named `dbVC0`, `dbVC1`, etc. Then, your problem is that you want to print all of them by number, but since they're variables, you can't.

One way to solve this would be to change how the 'subsets' are declared. Instead of

```
dfVC0 = ...
dfVC1 = ...
```

you could make one `dfVC` variable that's a dict, that holds all the others at their proper indices.

```
dfVC = {}
dfVC[0] = ...
dfVC[1] = ...
```

which would then allow you to access the various `dbVC` subsets in the way you're currently trying to.

---

But changing such a large part of the program isn't always possible. What you might be able to do instead is to figure out which object the `dfVC`s are attached to, and grab them by string.

If they're in the local namespace (i.e. were declared in the same function as you're currently executing in), you can call the built-in `locals()` to get a dict that you can then try to find your key in:

```
for x in range(20):
    sname = f'dfVC{x}'
    print(locals()[sname])
```

`globals()` can be used similarly, if your 'subsets' are in the global scope (i.e. declared outside of the current function).

And if your `dfVC` variables are attached to a class or module (or something else that behaves like a namespace), you can retrieve them using the built-in `getattr()` function:

```
for x in range(20):
    sname = f'dfVC{x}'
    print(getattr(self, sname)) # replace self with whichever object has the dbVC attached to it
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!